# How to get (neo)vim to highlight underscore numbers like normal numbers?

Tags: neovim

In Python files, `1_000_000` is not being higlighted the same way as `1000000`, but I would like them to all be highlighted as numeric literals.

desired output:

```py
(10000, 10_000, 0x0affbb, 0x0a_ff_bb)
```

my current output:

[image: 10000 and 0x0affbb are highlighted, 10_000 and 0x0a_ff_bb are not]

10000 and 0x0affbb are highlighted as numeric literals, 10_000 and 0x0a_ff_bb are not highlighted (at all?).

This is the same in neovim 0.8.3 (my editor) and Vim 9.0.

I would like to make all these literals to have the same highlighting, how can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solves the problem for integer I would add the following line in your `.vimrc`:

```
syn match pythonNumber "\<\%([1-9]\%(\d\|_\)*\|0\)\>"
```

For Vim 9.0 the file `$VIM/vim90/syntax/python.vim` defines the Python syntax.
It contains the following line that identify with integers:

```
syn match pythonNumber "\<\%([1-9]\d*\|0\)[Ll]\=\>"
```

But it doesn't support `_` within numbers.

The other patterns should also be corrected:

```
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[oO]\=\%(\o\|_\)\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[xX]\%(\x\|_\)\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[bB][01_]\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\%([1-9]\%(\d\|_\)*\|0\)\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*[jJ]\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*[eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*[jJ]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*\.\%([eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*\)\=[jJ]\=\%(\W\|$\)\@="
syn match pythonNumber "\%(^\|\W\)\zs\d*\.\d\%(\d\|_\)*\%([eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*\)\=[jJ]\=\>"
```

Or slightly better (forbidding the trailing `_`):

```
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[oO]\=\%(\o\|_\)\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[xX]\%(\x\|_\)\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<0[bB][01_]\+[Ll]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\%([1-9]\%(\d\|_\)*\|0\)\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*[jJ]\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*[eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*[jJ]\=\>"
syn match pythonNumber "\<\d\%(\d\|_\)*\.\%([eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*\)\=[jJ]\=\%(\W\|$\)\@="
syn match pythonNumber "\%(^\|\W\)\zs\d*\.\d\%(\d\|_\)*\%([eE][+-]\=\d\%(\d\|_\)*\)\=[jJ]\=\>"
```

Comment: I suppose this could be considered as an improvement to Vim. I have created a [bug report](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11978) and created a pull [request](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/11979)

Comment: Thanks for reporting the problem :-)